# How do I check if a a value exists in an array and if it does increase it

Tags: php

I have the following code. i want the `elseif` part to check if `$pId` is already in the array and if it is i want to increase its `quantity` and `price` rather than adding a new `$pId` to the array.

I don't know if i am using the wrong method or if my array structure is wrong but i cant get it to increase those values

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][] = $pid;
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid']['price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid']['quantity'] = $quantity;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_items'] = $quantity;
}elseif(array_key_exists($pid, $_SESSION['cart'])){
    //increase price
    //increase quantity
}else{
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][] = $pid;
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid']['price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] += $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_items'] += $quantity;
}
```

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa current value plus new value. eg `price +=`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an extra dimension to the array so you could easily select it.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array('pid' => array(), 'total_price' => 0, 'total_items' => 0);
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid]['price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_items'] = $quantity;
}elseif(array_key_exists($pid, $_SESSION['cart']['pid'])){
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid]['price'] = 'new price';
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid]['quantity'] = 'new quantity';
}else{
    $_SESSION['cart']['pid'][$pid]['price'] = $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_price'] += $price;
    $_SESSION['cart']['total_items'] += $quantity;
}
```

I don't know what `pid` stands for, but at first glance it doesn't really look descriptive. Maybe `products` would be a better key?